# Failed to create a view in Jenkins using jenkinsapi

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to create a bunch of Nested Views in Jenkins using Python and jenkinsapi.

The code is as following:

```
jenkins_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
api = Jenkins(jenkins_url, 'jenkins_admin', 'jenkins_password')
logger.info('view_name is %s' %view_name)
new_view = api.views.create(view_name, Views.NESTED_VIEW)
```

Everything goes well if I disable Authorization and allow 'Anyone can do anything' but fails with user/password authentication. We are using Active Directory and the user has Administrative privileges.

The failure is:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /api/python **HTTP/1.1" 200 3290**
INFO:root: view_name is 9.8
INFO:jenkinsapi.views:Creating "hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView" view "9.8"
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /createView **HTTP/1.1" 302 0**
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /view/9.8/configure **HTTP/1.1" 401 1445**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "JenkinsNewVersionJobsItems.py", line 46, in <module>
    top_view = NewVersionJobsItemsUtils.createView(short_version, api, NESTED)
  File "/tmp/NewVersionJobsItemsUtils.py", line 35, in createView
    new_view = parent_view.views.create(view_name, Views.NESTED_VIEW)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/jenkinsapi/views.py", line 103, in create
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/jenkinsapi/utils/requester.py", line 117, in post_and_confirm_status
jenkinsapi.custom_exceptions.JenkinsAPIException: Operation failed. url=http://127.0.0.1/view/9.8/configure, data={'json': '{"name": "9.8", "mode": "hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView"}', 'name': '9.8', 'Submit': 'OK', 'mode': 'hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView'}, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, status=401, text=<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>**Error 401 Invalid password/token for user: jenkins**</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
```

I see that authentication passed, the view was created and I was redirected (HTTP 302) to its configuration page, than failed with wrong password error.

After execution I can see the newly created view, running the script again finds the view, creates the next one and fails again with the same error. The problem is that I need a dozen of such views.

Could anyone help or point me the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,

jenkinsapi maintainer here.

Would you mind opening an issue on Github (https://github.com/salimfadhley/jenkinsapi)?

Please also provide there your real code, not only one that creates top view. I can't reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior if you try to create a nested view, but do not have the Nested Views plugin installed.  Perhaps this is your issue?